# combine activerecord query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I combine results from two queries?  For example, if I wanted to return both the first and last records for a model, how might I do this (the actual thing I want to do is more complicated, but uses the same premise).  Here's what I've tried

```
Project.first & Project.last
Project.first + Project.last
Project.first.concat(Project.last)
Project.first.merge(Project.last)
```

Comment: Can you not do `[Person.first, Person.last]`?

Comment: ok, strange, I ended up getting it working with + in my html.erb file but when I test it in the console, it doesn't work.  thanks for your help!

Comment: Potentially, since I don't know what your view looks like, the reason that `+` works is because both models get sent the message `to_s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question could be answered in a variety of ways (as it's a little ambiguous)...

I'm assuming though that you're after a traversable data structure, like an Array or a Hash (since you were using `concat` and `merge`).

Based on your example, potentially, the simplest solution is:

`[Project.first, Project.last]`